# In android studio 3.0, I am facing compile time error

Tags: android

Facing the following compile time error

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Maggique1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt2.exe with arguments {link -I C:\Users\Maggique1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar --manifest C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -R @C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\aapt-temp\aapt-resources-list.txt --auto-add-overlay --java C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -o C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt --no-version-vectors}
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Maggique1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt2.exe with arguments {link -I C:\Users\Maggique1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar --manifest C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -R @C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\aapt-temp\aapt-resources-list.txt --auto-add-overlay --java C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -o C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Maggique1\AndroidStudioProjects\Instantapp\base\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt --no-version-vectors}
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Maggique1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt2.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':base:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: For me the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant Apps - Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command' finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105317/instant-apps-errororg-gradle-process-internal-execexception-process-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your default Language displaying numbers to one supporting "."