# Instant Apps - Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am trying to build my first instant app which was introduced in Google IO 2017. I have downloaded Google Instant Apps SDK and target `minSDKVersion` to 23

I created a first project and I am facing below errors while trying to build it. Is there anyone who is also facing same errors for building Instant apps ? Is this because of some bug in build process of them ?

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :base:generateDebugSources, :base:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :base:mockableAndroidJar, :feature:generateDebugSources, :feature:mockableAndroidJar, :feature:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :instantapp:generateDebugSources]

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt2.exe with arguments {link -I C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar --manifest C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -R @C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\aapt-temp\aapt-resources-list.txt --auto-add-overlay --java C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -o C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt --no-version-vectors}

Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt2.exe with arguments {link -I C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar --manifest C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -R @C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\aapt-temp\aapt-resources-list.txt --auto-add-overlay --java C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -o C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt --no-version-vectors}

Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt2.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':base:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 3s
Information:4 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Clean project, Rebuild and Run app

Comment: @Mohammadnabil Tried, but no luck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43385937/4336740

Comment: @Mohammadnabil I am using embedded JDK (recommended) http://imgur.com/a/FcVVj

Comment: I don't have embedded option http://imgur.com/a/IuUBN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build your instant apps, you should use build-tools\26.0.0-rc1 and above. It looks like you are using 25.0.2.

Comment: This helped me, I installed build-tools 26.0.0-rc2

Comment: Thanks dude it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Set up a development environment for Android Instant Apps

> **To develop an instant app, you need the following:**

- A development machine running Linux, macOS, or Windows.
- JDK 1.8
- Android Studio 3.0 or higher 
  -An environment variable called ANDROID_HOME that points to the location 
  of the Android SDK on your
  development machine. 
  **In Android Studio, use the Android SDK Manager to install the following packages:**
- Android SDK 6.0 or higher
- Android SDK Build Tools 26.x or higher
- Android SDK Tools 25.x or higher
- Android SDK Platform Tools 25.x or higher
- Android Support Library (latest) Android Repository (latest)
  [Reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html#check_your_system_requirements)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with 3.1 Canary2 on a Project I am about to modularize to Instant and Installed. I updated the versions to the latest of the list above and set the environment value, but adb would not initialize. So I updated to Canary6, which then required another Gradle upgrade. Then the classpath had to be manually updated to alpha06. After that I got a clean Build but running in emulator failed with "qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working". I installed V6.2.1 of Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator. What do I do now?

I had been working with the Topeka sample code and thought there might be some inconsistency with all the version upgrades. So I reverted to the copy of my Project instead. But now that application installation failed with "Could not access the Package Manager ... uninstall it?"

A couple more tries and discovered that the (sole) activity was not accessible. As soon as I changed the directory name in the path, which was a leftover from having made this test copy of the Project, Gradle built, the APK loaded, and all is right.

Whew! Hope this helps others.