# Gradle build error in AndroidStudio 3.0 Canary 1

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I was trying to make new project in AndroidStudio 3.0 Canary 1. But the project was not building successfully due to following errors.

```
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt2.exe with arguments {link -I C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar --manifest F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -R @F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\aapt-temp\aapt-resources-list.txt --auto-add-overlay --java F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -o F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt --no-version-vectors}
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt2.exe with arguments {link -I C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar --manifest F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\manifest\androidTest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -R @F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\aapt-temp\aapt-resources-list.txt --auto-add-overlay --java F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\debug -o F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\res\androidTest\debug\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols F:\Workspace\InstaApp\base\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt --no-version-vectors}
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt2.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Help me for this error. Thanks in advance ; )

Comment: Can you add the architecture of your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant Apps - Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command' finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105317/instant-apps-errororg-gradle-process-internal-execexception-process-command)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in buildToolsVersion. Try to change it to 26.0.0-rc2.

I had the same error when trying to add custom font as font-file in resources (this is a new feature of Android O), but this feature works only on 26+.